# How to add an emojibutton outside the textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, emoji, ember-emojione

I am using emojionearea for add emoji (smiley).

```
https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea
```

I want to add an emoji button outside the text-area. So please tell me if there is any option available for that !

What I already tried.

It's also available at
     https://jsfiddle.net/1v03Lqnu/12/  (see all emoji-button is inside text-box or textarea and that I want to change I required outside )

Answer (score 0):

The `standalone` mode of the `emojionearea` jQuery plugin.

It's much more tedious, though. You'll have to manually care about pasting & rendering emojis into your textarea.

The `ember-emojione` addon that you've referenced is able to do what you need, but it's an Ember addon, has nothing to do with jQuery or `emojionearea`.